# Wavelet analysis, scaling filter: where does the square root of 2 go to?

Tags: wavelet

In their great book "*Wavelet methods for time series analysis*" (2006), Percival & Walden state on p. 83 that the first-round pyramid algorithm scaling filter coefficients $\tilde{V}_{i,t}$ can be approximated by

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=-\frac{N}{4}+1}^{\frac{N}{4}}{\chi_{k}e^{i 2 \pi t k/N}}$$

arguing that $2^{1/2} \tilde{V}_{i,t}$

> is formed by filtering [the time series] $\{X_{t}\}$ with the low-pass filter $\{g_l\}$ with nominal pass-band $[-1/4, 1/4]$ ...

Why is it $\tilde{V}_{i,t}$ and not $2^{1/2} \tilde{V}_{i,t}$ which is approximated by the above expression?

My understanding is that the approximation is due to limiting the frequency domain of the inverse DFT according to the pass-band of the filter.